# JSP: Evaluate EL expression in SimpleTagSupport - getExpressionEvaluator deprecated? (Spring MVC)

Tags: jsp, tags, el, expression-evaluation

I have a tag class that extends javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.**SimpleTagSupport**.
I want to process its body BEFORE the Expression Language is evaluated, so I have:

```
<body-content>tagdependent</body-content>
```

in my .tld file.

After doing my stuff with the body, I'd like to process the EL.
Currently I use something like this:

```
    VariableResolver variableResolver = getJspContext().getVariableResolver();
    Object evaluatedCode = null;
    try {
        evaluatedCode = getJspContext().getExpressionEvaluator().evaluate( snippetCode, String.class, variableResolver, null);
    } catch (ELException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException( e );
    }
```

But the docs say **getVariableResolver** and **getExpressionEvaluator** are **deprecated**.

I suppose that the right way to do it is to use **ELContext**.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Deprecated. As of JSP 2.1, replaced by JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()

See - 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/2.1/docs/jsp-2_1-pfd2/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#getExpressionEvaluator()